# Explode values in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am doing know Laravel webservice. Actually my result is

```
{"key_skills_details":[{"id":31,"key_skills":"anroid,php,html"}]}
```

but I want

```
{"key_skills_details":[{"id":31,"key_skills":"anroid"}],[{"id":31,"key_skills":"php"}],[{"id":31,"key_skills":"html"}]}
```

My code is below.

```
public function getKeyskillshow(){

    $user_id=$_REQUEST['user_id'];

    $profiles="SELECT `id` FROM `abserve_keyskill` where `user_id`=".$user_id;
    $details=\DB::SELECT($profiles);
    $reason=\DB::SELECT("SELECT `key_skills` FROM `abserve_keyskill` where `user_id`=".$user_id);   
    $var=explode(',',$reason);


    $response['key_skills_details']=$details;
    echo json_encode($response);exit;
}
```

Comment: Store the data in array

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this, hope this helps you

```
public function getKeyskillshow(){
  $user_id=$_REQUEST['user_id'];
  $profiles="SELECT `id` FROM `abserve_keyskill` where `user_id`=".$user_id;
  $details=\DB::SELECT($profiles);
  $reason=\DB::SELECT("SELECT `key_skills` FROM `abserve_keyskill` where `user_id`=".$user_id);   
  $array_of_reasons = explode(',', $reason->key_skills);
  $array_details = new array();
  for($i=0; $i<count($array_of_reasons); $i++)
  {
    $array_details[$i] = array('id' => $user_id, 'key_skills' => $array_of_reasons[$i]);
  }
  $response['key_skills_details']=$array_details;
  echo json_encode($response);exit;
}
```